# deep merge but only if values are not empty in js

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm using lodash mergeWith and all works great with the below function but once I add deep nested objects then the customizer is not taking the deep nested object into consideration.

```
const merge = (main, base) => {
  return mergeWith(main, base, (a, b) => {
    return b === "" ? a : b;
  });
};
```

this works

```
const main = {
 name: 'tim'
 age: '24'
}

const base = {
  name: ''
  age: '20'
}

const merged = merge(main,base);
// {name: tim, age: 20}
```

this does not work as intended

```
const main = {
 name: 'tim'
 age: '24'
 data: { height: '11', width: '10' } 
}

const base = {
  name: ''
  age: '20'
  data: { height: '21', width: '' } 
}

const merged = merge(main,base);
// {name: tim, age: 20, data: { height: '21', width: '' } }
```

Its merging width even though its empty. It should be
// {name: tim, age: 20, data: { height: '21', width: '10' } }

Answer (score 2):

You need to return `undefined` if it needs to traverse the object. So your `mergeWith` comparison should be:

```
const merged = _.mergeWith(main,base,(a,b) => {
  if (typeof b === 'object') return;
    return b === "" ? a : b;
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9q3zd8y/)

Comment: I would replace `typeof b === 'object'` with `_.isObject(b)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom function to generate the merged object. For missing values, copies from the source object and for other keep using the target object. It will work for nested object as well.

In case you have array, you have to modify below function.

```js
const main = { name: 'tim', age: '24', data: { height: '11', width: '10' } };

const base = { name: '', age: '20', data: { height: '21', width: '' } }

const deepMerge = (source, target) => {
  return Object.keys(source).reduce((r, k) => {
    if (typeof source[k] === 'object') {
      r[k] = deepMerge(source[k], target[k]);
      return r;
    }
    r[k] = !target[k] ? source[k] : target[k];
    return r;
  }, {});
}

console.log(deepMerge(main, base));
```